# Change page from server after time period over ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redirect

I'm fairly new to C# and ASP.NET, and I'm trying to built a web app to create and answer exams.

The app consists of admin who creates the exams, and students who takes them.

My `Exam` model has a `startTime` and a `durationInMinutes` property.

```
public class Exam : IExam
{
    [Key]
    public int ExamID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public int ExamDurationInMinutes { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

When student logs in the app will show the exams they have for this day, and when the time comes, allow them to take it.

I need to somehow, while the student is taking the test, to always check if the test had ended, and if so, save the data that has entered so far, and throw them out of the test.

I don't want to do this with JS and AJAX because it can be manipulated with the client. It must be something the server controls.

I have tried experimenting with Timer but was unable to redirect to another action when timer elapsed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't need to count the ticks every second to actively block the client. All you need is a time (value of `DateTime`) to check when the client submits the test. That time value (the latest time by which the test must be submitted) is checked against the time the test is submitted. For the client side display which shows some cue when the time is over, you can use client code (javascript for web) to sync the time with the server (at the time of starting the test on the client). That's the simplest way to implement (don't even need code to push client from server such as by using `signalr`)

Comment: What do you mean by syncing the time with the server?
 also i was thinking about saving the exam every answer, to have it saved in case of crashing of some sort (on client side).
should that be done with AJAX?